# How can I get the caret position from a textbox in another application? (Not the coordinates, but the actual index inside of the textbox)

Tags: c#, winapi, automation, mouseevent

I need to retrieve the index of the caret inside a textbox in the focused window, maybe using UI Automation, or maybe a Win32 API function, if there's any function that cat do that.
And I emphasize, I don't mean the x,y coordinates, but the index of the caret inside the text of the textbox. How can I do that?
Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52592652/get-text-and-caret-from-a-textbox-in-another-application) similar question.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer in the link you added? This is the way to go

Comment: @SimonMourier look at the comments of the post, this approach helps me recieve only the x,y coordinates, which is, as I mentioned, not what I need.

Comment: If the textbox is a standard Windows textbox, then you can send the textbox an [`EM_CHARFROMPOS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-charfrompos) window message to convert client coordinates to a character index. Or, send it an [`EM_GETSEL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-getsel) window message to get the start/end indexes of the currently selected text, one of which will be the same as the caret position.

Comment: EM_CHARFROMPOS always return 0 @RemyLebeau

Comment: @TalXD did you convert your coordinates from screen coordinates to client coordinated first?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I didn't know that I need to, I don't know what it means.

Comment: @TalXD there are two kinds of coordinates, coordinates within the overall [virtual screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/the-virtual-screen), and coordinates within the client area of each HWND. The other solution you linked to says it provides the caret position in screen coordinates. `EM_CHARFROMPOS` takes client coordinates. You can use `ScreenToClient()` or `MapWindowPoints()` to convert screen coordinates into client coordinates.

Comment: Thanks. and how do I use EM_getsel? How do I cast the int value to the start and end index? @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use UI Automation for that, and especially the [IUIAutomationTextPattern2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nn-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationtextpattern2) interface that has a [GetCaretRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationtextpattern2-getcaretrange) method.

Here are two sample Console app (C++ and C# code) that run continuously and display the caret position for the current element under the mouse:

C++ version

```
int main()
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    {
        CComPtr<IUIAutomation> automation;

        // make sure you use CLSID_CUIAutomation8, *not* CLSID_CUIAutomation
        automation.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation8);
        do
        {
            POINT pt;
            if (GetCursorPos(&pt))
            {
                CComPtr<IUIAutomationElement> element;
                automation->ElementFromPoint(pt, &element);
                if (element)
                {
                    CComBSTR name;
                    element->get_CurrentName(&name);
                    wprintf(L"Watched element %s\n", name);

                    CComPtr<IUIAutomationTextPattern2> text;
                    element->GetCurrentPatternAs(UIA_TextPattern2Id, IID_PPV_ARGS(&text));
                    if (text)
                    {
                        // get document range
                        CComPtr<IUIAutomationTextRange> documentRange;
                        text->get_DocumentRange(&documentRange);

                        // get caret range
                        BOOL active = FALSE;
                        CComPtr<IUIAutomationTextRange> range;
                        text->GetCaretRange(&active, &range);
                        if (range)
                        {
                            // compare caret start with document start
                            int caretPos = 0;
                            range->CompareEndpoints(TextPatternRangeEndpoint_Start, documentRange, TextPatternRangeEndpoint_Start, &caretPos);
                            wprintf(L" caret is at %i\n", caretPos);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Sleep(500);
        } while (TRUE);
    }
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

C# version

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // needs 'using UIAutomationClient;'
    // to reference UIA, don't use the .NET assembly
    // but instead, reference the UIAutomationClient dll as a COM object
    // and set Embed Interop Types to False for the UIAutomationClient reference in the C# project
    var automation = new CUIAutomation8();
    do
    {
        var cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;
        var element = automation.ElementFromPoint(new tagPOINT { x = cursor.X, y = cursor.Y });
        if (element != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Watched element " + element.CurrentName);
            var guid = typeof(IUIAutomationTextPattern2).GUID;
            var ptr = element.GetCurrentPatternAs(UIA_PatternIds.UIA_TextPattern2Id, ref guid);
            if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                var pattern = (IUIAutomationTextPattern2)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(ptr);
                if (pattern != null)
                {
                    var documentRange = pattern.DocumentRange;
                    var caretRange = pattern.GetCaretRange(out _);
                    if (caretRange != null)
                    {
                        var caretPos = caretRange.CompareEndpoints(
                            TextPatternRangeEndpoint.TextPatternRangeEndpoint_Start,
                            documentRange,
                            TextPatternRangeEndpoint.TextPatternRangeEndpoint_Start);
                        Console.WriteLine(" caret is at " + caretPos);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
    while (true);
}
```

The trick is to use the [IUIAutomationTextRange::CompareEndpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationtextrange-compareendpoints) method that allows you to compare the caret range with another range, for example the whole document range.

Note there are drawbacks:

- some apps don't support any MSAA/UIA introspection at all, or don't support the text pattern. For these, there are simply no solution (even using Windows API I think)
- some apps report the caret incorrectly, especially when you *select* text (so, with a moving caret). For example with Notepad, moving <kbd>LEFT</kbd> while pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> will select backwards but for some reason UIA doesn't update caret pos. I think it's a problem with Notepad because it also has caret issue with IME (Input Method Editor, like the Emoji editor you can summon using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> keyboard combination) which also uses the global caret position. There's no problem with Wordpad for example.

Comment: Can I do the same thing in c#?
Also Thanks! @SimonMourier

Comment: I have copied yor code, and for some reason vs doesn't find classes like CUIAutomation8 and IUIAutomationTextPattern2

Comment: @TalXD - have you referenced UIAutomationClient dll as a COM object, not using standard .NET assemblies? What Windows version are you using?

Comment: win 10, and about an hour ago I did and tried your code. But for some reason it doesn't work on google chrome, it probably doesn't support AutomationUI. 
Thanks!!!

Comment: @TalXD - chrome can be extensively configured for automation in general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47216824/does-microsoft-ui-automation-framework-work-with-chrome-python-and-java-apps

Comment: @SimonMouirer thanks a lot! but it is still not what I need, I'm trying to know what is the caret position whenever chrome is opened. But maybe I can make chrome open in this mode whenever it's opened. Is this possible?

Comment: @TalXD - for any given installation, this is not possible AFAIK. You can configure a special shortcut for accessibility, or detect accessibility is not there and tell the user