# C# how do I get the caret position inside a textbox in Google Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, winapi, ui-automation

I'm trying to get the caret position of the active textbox in google chrome, from a hidden console.

For other applications, I used approaches like win-api and UI automation, but since chrome does not support both of them, the only way I could think of is simulating `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `DownArrow`, copying the data, and then get the selected text from the clipboard which is the text from the caret position to the end of the paragraph (I already know how to retrive the text).

It works, but I wanted to know if there is any better solution (maybe by forcing chrome to be opened on Native accessibility API support from code, if it's possible. look at [this](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/182104-google-chrome-automation-with-uia/) link).

Comment: [Simon's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61368790/how-can-i-get-the-caret-position-from-a-textbox-in-another-application-not-the) works for me for Google Chrome.

Comment: Are you on accessibility mode? @RitaHan-MSFT

Comment: I don't do anything about "forcing chrome to be opened on Native accessibility". How to confirm if it is on accessibility mode?

Comment: enter chrome://accessibility/, and check if 'Native accessibility API support' is turned on. @RitaHan-MSFT

Comment: Thanks for info. Yes, it is turned on for me.